# JHipster: JWT and Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, spring-boot, authentication, jwt, jhipster

I have a new JHipster project initialized with JWT Authentication.

I'd like to integrate my application with my Wordpress site authentication.
Also, I don't want to use external providers like Okta or Keycloack.

I've already (successfully) used a CustomAuthenticationProvider with a lib that exploits xmlrpc, but now I'd like to use JWT, as I would have a cleaner integration.

I added a JWT plugin to my WP installation.

The fact is, I don't fully understand JHipster structure and where I have to switch the JWT endpoint.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: REST controllers you have to adapt are AccountResource, UserJWTController and UserResource. Main point is the format of your WP token, what are the claims that could be extracted from it by JHipster. Not sure JWT in JHipster is the most adequate choice for this architecture because in this case JHipster is the authentication provider so it does provide many things you don't need like users/authorities tables in backend and user management in frontend. Generating a JHipster project with external authentication like KeyCloak or UAA could be a better choice, especially if WP supports oauth2.

Comment: Please edit your question with more details rather than commenting, it'll be easier to follow.